# mysql & INTO OUTFILE - escape or replace new lines in data

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, into-outfile

I have the following sql statement to out put a sql table to a csv file.

Some data found in the column 'content' includes new line charactors which is causing issues, is there a way to replace all \n with 's?

```
SELECT id, title, content 
INTO OUTFILE '/content.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM content
```

Answer (score 3):

```
REPLACE( IFNULL(content , ''), '\n' , '<br/>' ) as content
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT id, title, REPLACE(content , CHR(13), ' ') as content
INTO OUTFILE '/content.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM content
```

where `CHR(13)` represents new line.